# Getting a path error in flutter using VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Just started using flutter. I'm assuming that there's an issue with my PATH but idk how to solve it. My emulator doesn't start when I try to run an app. Couldn't find any information on the internet either. I'm at the point of frustration...

**Command 'Flutter: Launch Emulator' resulted in an error (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'emulatorPath' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: emulatorPath)**

Comment: Hi, what operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you have the Flutter & Dart extensions ? When you `flutter doctor -v`, is the path of your Android SDK showing ?

Comment: I recommend using Android Studio on Windows and Linux. I always had problems with Visual Studio Code and Kotlin/Flutter. So it is best to use Android Studio.

Comment: Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67293) in Flutter that occurred if you didn't have an Android SDK set up.

It's since been fixed and the fix is available in the Flutter stable channel.